# MediaPlayer out of memory / Virtual accordion

Tags: android, media-player

I'am currently trying to make a accordion virtual instrument.
So I want to loop a sample until I push a button and stop when the button is released.

I have a lot of problems using `MediaPlayer`:

1) I have been usiing `.pause()` on last version and I get some preliminary errors: After a certain number of button played, they was no sound for any new button I pushed, but the one I have pushed before the "mute" was still working. so I was expecting that was a problem with `.pause()` and memory usage so I have using `.stop()` and after `.prepareAsyc()` but then I get new errors:

-At the beginning some sound and works fine.
-After a while, everybutton have no sound.
-After trying again the app crashes...

```
01-22 11:07:59.062: D/ActivityManager(55): Received spurious death notification for thread android.os.BinderProxy@43d797f0
01-22 11:07:59.182: D/AudioSink(30): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
01-22 11:07:59.442: W/AudioFlinger(30): write blocked for 107 msecs, 1 delayed writes, thread 0xb388
01-22 11:08:00.182: D/AudioSink(30): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
01-22 11:08:04.890: W/AudioFlinger(30): write blocked for 93 msecs, 9 delayed writes, thread 0xb388
01-22 11:08:06.042: D/AudioSink(30): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
01-22 11:08:07.042: D/AudioSink(30): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
01-22 11:08:07.702: D/AudioSink(30): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
01-22 11:08:08.412: D/AudioSink(30): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
01-22 11:08:46.616: W/AudioFlinger(30): write blocked for 72 msecs, 23 delayed writes, thread 0xb388
01-22 11:08:54.570: W/AudioFlinger(30): write blocked for 90 msecs, 42 delayed writes, thread 0xb388
01-22 11:09:00.463: W/AudioFlinger(30): write blocked for 85 msecs, 68 delayed writes, thread 0xb388
01-22 11:09:05.752: W/AudioFlinger(30): write blocked for 77 msecs, 93 delayed writes, thread 0xb388
01-22 11:09:47.431: W/AudioFlinger(30): write blocked for 105 msecs, 97 delayed writes, thread 0xb388
01-22 11:09:52.872: D/AudioSink(30): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
01-22 11:09:53.036: W/AudioFlinger(30): write blocked for 80 msecs, 114 delayed writes, thread 0xb388
01-22 11:09:53.532: D/AudioSink(30): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
01-22 11:09:57.282: D/AudioSink(30): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
01-22 11:09:58.066: W/AudioFlinger(30): write blocked for 73 msecs, 140 delayed writes, thread 0xb388
01-22 11:09:58.843: D/AudioSink(30): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
01-22 11:09:59.582: D/AudioSink(30): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
01-22 11:10:00.553: D/AudioSink(30): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
01-22 11:10:01.512: D/AudioSink(30): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
01-22 11:10:02.232: D/AudioSink(30): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
01-22 11:10:02.952: D/AudioSink(30): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
01-22 11:10:03.214: W/AudioFlinger(30): write blocked for 93 msecs, 157 delayed writes, thread 0xb388
01-22 11:10:03.802: D/AudioSink(30): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
01-22 11:10:04.992: D/AudioSink(30): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
01-22 11:10:06.062: D/AudioSink(30): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
01-22 11:10:07.352: D/AudioSink(30): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
01-22 11:10:07.902: D/AudioSink(30): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
01-22 11:10:08.282: W/AudioFlinger(30): write blocked for 93 msecs, 172 delayed writes, thread 0xb388
01-22 11:10:09.932: D/AudioSink(30): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
01-22 11:10:10.562: D/AudioSink(30): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
01-22 11:10:10.574: E/AudioFlinger(30): not enough memory for AudioTrack size=49216
01-22 11:10:10.574: D/MemoryDealer(30):   AudioTrack (0x189460, size=1048576)
01-22 11:10:10.574: D/MemoryDealer(30):     0: 00189498 | 0x00000000 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:10.574: D/MemoryDealer(30):     1: 00189570 | 0x0000C040 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:10.574: D/MemoryDealer(30):     2: 0018cc90 | 0x00018080 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:10.574: D/MemoryDealer(30):     3: 00189b28 | 0x000240C0 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:10.574: D/MemoryDealer(30):     4: 001939c8 | 0x00030100 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:10.574: D/MemoryDealer(30):     5: 00196c40 | 0x0003C140 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:10.574: D/MemoryDealer(30):     6: 00199eb0 | 0x00048180 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:10.574: D/MemoryDealer(30):     7: 0019a8b8 | 0x000541C0 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:10.574: D/MemoryDealer(30):     8: 0019ad10 | 0x00060200 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:10.574: D/MemoryDealer(30):     9: 001a15d0 | 0x0006C240 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:10.574: D/MemoryDealer(30):    10: 001a1a18 | 0x00078280 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:10.574: D/MemoryDealer(30):    11: 001a50a8 | 0x000842C0 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:10.574: D/MemoryDealer(30):    12: 001aeb00 | 0x00090300 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:10.574: D/MemoryDealer(30):    13: 001ab990 | 0x0009C340 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:10.574: D/MemoryDealer(30):    14: 001b4fb8 | 0x000A8380 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:10.574: D/MemoryDealer(30):    15: 001b8660 | 0x000B43C0 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:10.574: D/MemoryDealer(30):    16: 001b54f0 | 0x000C0400 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:10.574: D/MemoryDealer(30):    17: 001bef78 | 0x000CC440 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:10.574: D/MemoryDealer(30):    18: 001c2608 | 0x000D8480 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:10.574: D/MemoryDealer(30):    19: 001b8ba8 | 0x000E44C0 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:10.574: D/MemoryDealer(30):    20: 001c8ab0 | 0x000F0500 | 0x0000C040 | A
01-22 11:10:10.574: E/AudioTrack(30): AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
01-22 11:10:10.574: E/AudioSink(30): Unable to create audio track
01-22 11:10:10.574: E/VorbisPlayer(30): mAudioSink open failed
01-22 11:10:11.292: D/AudioSink(30): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
01-22 11:10:11.292: E/AudioFlinger(30): not enough memory for AudioTrack size=49216
01-22 11:10:11.304: D/MemoryDealer(30):   AudioTrack (0x189460, size=1048576)
01-22 11:10:11.304: D/MemoryDealer(30):     0: 00189498 | 0x00000000 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:11.304: D/MemoryDealer(30):     1: 00189570 | 0x0000C040 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:11.304: D/MemoryDealer(30):     2: 0018cc90 | 0x00018080 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:11.304: D/MemoryDealer(30):     3: 00189b28 | 0x000240C0 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:11.304: D/MemoryDealer(30):     4: 001939c8 | 0x00030100 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:11.304: D/MemoryDealer(30):     5: 00196c40 | 0x0003C140 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:11.304: D/MemoryDealer(30):     6: 00199eb0 | 0x00048180 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:11.304: D/MemoryDealer(30):     7: 0019a8b8 | 0x000541C0 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:11.304: D/MemoryDealer(30):     8: 0019ad10 | 0x00060200 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:11.304: D/MemoryDealer(30):     9: 001a15d0 | 0x0006C240 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:11.304: D/MemoryDealer(30):    10: 001a1a18 | 0x00078280 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:11.304: D/MemoryDealer(30):    11: 001a50a8 | 0x000842C0 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:11.304: D/MemoryDealer(30):    12: 001aeb00 | 0x00090300 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:11.304: D/MemoryDealer(30):    13: 001ab990 | 0x0009C340 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:11.304: D/MemoryDealer(30):    14: 001b4fb8 | 0x000A8380 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:11.304: D/MemoryDealer(30):    15: 001b8660 | 0x000B43C0 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:11.304: D/MemoryDealer(30):    16: 001b54f0 | 0x000C0400 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:11.304: D/MemoryDealer(30):    17: 001bef78 | 0x000CC440 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:11.304: D/MemoryDealer(30):    18: 001c2608 | 0x000D8480 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:11.304: D/MemoryDealer(30):    19: 001b8ba8 | 0x000E44C0 | 0x0000C040 | A 
01-22 11:10:11.304: D/MemoryDealer(30):    20: 001c8ab0 | 0x000F0500 | 0x0000C040 | A
01-22 11:10:11.304: E/AudioTrack(30): AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
01-22 11:10:11.304: E/VorbisPlayer(30): mAudioSink open failed
```

Also this is the code of my activity:

```
package com.soundbutton;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public  class Main extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {


@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        final MediaPlayer sound01 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);
        final MediaPlayer sound02 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound2);
        final MediaPlayer sound03 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound3);
        final MediaPlayer sound04 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound4);


    ///////////////////////////////////First line/////////////////////    
        final Button b11 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.sound1);
        b11.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   
                sound01.setLooping(true);
                sound01.start();            return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                sound01.stop();
                sound01.prepareAsync();

                return true; }  return true;        }});


        final Button b12 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.sound2);
        b12.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   
                sound02.setLooping(true);
                sound02.start();            return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                sound02.stop(); 
                sound02.prepareAsync();
                return true; }  return true;        }}); 

        final Button b13 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.sound3);
        b13.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   
                sound03.setLooping(true);
                sound03.start();            return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                sound03.stop();
                sound03.prepareAsync();
                return true; }  return true;        }}); 

        final Button b14 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.sound4);
        b14.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   
                sound04.setLooping(true);
                sound04.start();            return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                sound04.stop(); 
                sound04.prepareAsync();         return true; }  return true;        }}); 

    }

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

}
```

Hope you can helps me ;)

Best
Ewen

Comment: You should try using `release()` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release())

Comment: I can't use release() because I need to be able to play another time the samples after the button is up ...

Comment: Did someone found the problem ?